# How to always open new file in current window in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, tabs

Whenever I open a file in Windows by double-clicking on it, Visual Studio Code opens that file in a new window even though VSCode is already running.

Any idea how to make it open the file in a new tab instead?

Comment: try adding the following setting in your User Settings file:
`"window.openFilesInNewWindow": "on"`

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to open a new file in Visual Studio Code is with *File* -> *Open File*.

Open Visual Studio Code and select *File* -> *Preferences* -> *Settings* -> *User* tab -> *Window* -> **New Window** -> **Open Files in New Window** -> from the dropdown menu select *off* (marked by the mouse cursor in the below screenshot). Also check the **Open Files in New Window** (the next one down in the list) dropdown menu selection. It should be set to *default*. These settings will make Visual Studio Code open files in a new tab instead of in a new window.

[image: Visual Studio Code]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: Hmm, thanks but I have this setting on "off" but the files still open in a new window. And I'm not opening the program with `--new-window` either. Is there anything that can make it open in a new window?

Answer (score 0):

In case FileZilla (or other ftp client), use below command to open file in same window of vs code editor.

1. Set VS code editor as default editor in FileZilla. menu: Edit > Setting > File editing. select custom editor and brows the vs code .exe file.
2. Go to menu: Edit > Setting > File type association. paste below command:

   html "C:\Users\della\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" --reuse-window
   js "C:\Users\della\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" --reuse-window

Thank you.